# What is the name of this movie about a secret group of freaks/monsters

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for the title of this movie I watched years ago set in modern times where the hero comes across this society of monsters (mutated people with strange powers) living underground in secret. If i remember correctly the entrance to their place was in a cemetery, possibly in a tomb. In any case the hero finds out he is really of of them and ends up helping them fights off humans come to kill them. In fact at some point I think a little girl was abducted and taken to the local police station where the hero had to rescue her before something happened (she was going to change shape/die/something). I think she was named Babette.

It's an 80s or 90s movie. I also have this impression it was also a book.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are thinking of Clive Barker's *[Nightbreed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100260/)*.

This was his follow-up directorial effort after *Hellraiser*, and is also based on his own written work. He had hoped at the time that this would be the first in a trilogy of films, but the luke-warm reception killed that idea.

[image]